Flutter set Smallest Width DP
I want my app to have the same look and feel with regards to the font sizes and space occupied by my widgets. Currently, in different phones with different smallest width and varying DP, the font sizes and space occupied is varying. I want to implement the app in such a way that the font sizes and space occupied should be constant across devices. How do I implement this in Flutter?

I get it. You can use "sizer" from pub.dev, which is dependent on your device's width and height. I was used in my many flutter app and it's look good for almost every device.
